# Couldn't an attacker alter a SAML Response data along with the signature and digest?

Tags: saml

Based on my understanding, the way signatures are generated in a SAML response is like this:

1. Pick the SAML Response (without the signature block)
2. Use the Service Provider's public key to generate a signature
3. Generate the digest
4. Add a signature block containing the signature + digest.
5. Also add the Service Provider's public key to the signature block.

I think that step #5 creates a security loophole. Step #5 is done because the Service Provider might have multiple keys and we need to tell the SP which key to use for the signature.

But now, an attacker could intercept the response, alter some values, use the public key from the SAML response to regenerate the signature and digest. This can defeat the entire point of the signature verification.

Is this a security loophole?
What prevents the tamperer from altering the signature/digest information?

Comment: How do you generate a signature from a public key??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2. Use the Service Provider's public key to generate a signature

This is where the error lies. A signature is *generated* using the private key, and is *verified* using the public key. Unless you have access to the private key, you cannot generate a signature, which verifies using the public key.

If you *do* have the private key, then yes, you can absolutely forge any signature you want.

Comment: This is a poor answer, because it doesn't much help OP in deciding who should have what keys. At best, it has a high-level answer that isn't going to be definitive for a newbie that would ask this level of question.

Comment: @AndrewK. My job is to answer the question, not explain every underlying technology related to the question. If you feel the answer is insufficient, feel free to write a better one.